# Monitor my downloading usage with python

Tags: python, download, port

I want to make a program in python which monitors my browsing and downloading data and shows me how much data I have downloaded in a day (or in a given time interval).

I don't want what I have downloaded, I just need to know how much data (the amount of data) that I have downloaded and/or browsed.

For that should I access the ports or something else?
How should I proceed ?

**Edit:** I am using Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: what do you mean by "keep tab on my browsing and downloading data?", maybe describing a concrete use-case would help.

Comment: I just need the amount of data that I have downloaded.

Comment: This will be platform dependant, you should add a description of your platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a basic idea of how to monitor my downloads. I basically take the data of packets and add it up

```
    #!/usr/bin/python2.7
    import pcap, dpkt, socket

    pc = pcap.pcap()
    ports = (80, 8080, 888, 443)

    def process():
      mem = 0
      sport = 0
      dport = 0
      try:
        for ts, pkt in pc:
          eth = dpkt.ethernet.Ethernet(pkt)
          ip = eth.data

          if ip.__class__ == dpkt.ip.IP:
            ip1, ip2 = map(socket.inet_ntoa, [ip.src, ip.dst])
            if ip.p == 6:
              I7 = ip.data
              sport, dport = [I7.sport, I7.dport]
            if sport in ports or dport in ports:
              if len(data) > 0:
                print 'From %s to %s, length: %d' %(ip1, ip2, len(I7.data))
                mem = mem + len(I7.data)
     except KeyboardInterrupt:
       return mem

    def main():
      mem = process()
      print float(mem/(1024*1024)), 'mb'
      return

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      main()
```

This prints source ip, dest ip, length of package until keybaordinterrupt is provided.

Comment: http://jayrambhia.wordpress.com/2012/01/12/monitor-your-browsingdownloading-data-via-python/